# What does it mean when the union of members of a set "spans" another set?

Tags: game-theory

In page 4, section 3 of [this paper](http://mlanctot.info/files/papers/nips09mccfr.pdf), they define a set $Q$ as a set of subsets of $Z$ "such that their union spans $Z$". Can someone please explain this part? I don't understand what this condition means? Say $Z$ is defined as follows:
$$Z= \left\{h_{1},\space h_{2}, \space h_{3} \right\} $$

Then how would $Q$ be defined, "such that the union of its members spans the set $Z$"? Is there even a unique $Q$?

Comment: This is question is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201034/what-does-it-mean-when-the-union-of-members-of-a-set-spans-another-set